# Can't Login to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, login, authentication

I am able to login to this site (Meta SO) using OpenID

I cannot do the same at Stack Overflow - I get an error.  Doesn't it make sense to allow an alternative way of logging in?  If the OpenID fails, then people are left without any way to login.  I really need to get in today to check something and no matter what I do it will not allow me.  Clearly OpenID is ok because I used it to get into this site.

What's going on with SO?

[EDIT]

After the 15th repeated attempt I was finally able to login.  But my point I think is still valid, what does one do in the event that the OpenID system fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a DNS issue on one of the web servers. It was unable to resolve any internet domain names. Should be resolved now.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks Jeff :)

But should there be an alternative way to login?  Or is this overkill given how simple the OpenID system is?  Is there a way to tie users to their openIDs on your side? (I am not too familliar with the technical details)

Answer (score 0):

What provider do you use? It's likely their fault - in which case you might want to use a different provider.

Comment: I did think about that.  I used google, however thinking it might be google, and not caring what provider I use, I tried some others, yahoo and livejournal - both of which I have an account, and no dice, same error there.